# What is the difference between a space and a comma in a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For instance, if I use this syntax here: `$('#itemid1 button').on('click', function () {` When will this function run? Is it when you click any button or an element with the id of `itemid1` or is it when you click a button that has the `itemid1` id, or something else entirely?

I think doing this: `$('#itemid1, button').on('click', function () {` would run a function every time you clicked a button or element with id of `itemid1`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `'#itemid1 button'` - Any `<button>` element contained within the element with the `id` "itemid1".  `'#itemid1, button'` - The element with the `id` "itemid1" or any `<button>` element.

Comment: Appreciate the answer! Thanks.